# How do I convert $_GET/$_POST params to URL segments in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Very simple. How can I convert this:

```
index.php/person/byAge?age=5 or index.php/person/byAge (with $_POSTed data)
```

to this:

```
index.php/person/byAge/5
```

I am using CodeIgniter 2.1.3

Comment: Look at Url routing and depending on the url required you also may need to change your .htaccess  http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: Can we assume person as controller and byAge as view files......

Answer (score 1):

For your specific issue you shouldn't need to edit .htaccess (if you are happy to still include the index.php in your URLs). Have a look at the Codeigniter uri class [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html)

Their documentation is the best thing about the framework IMO, and would explain any of this far better than I could.

In particular look out for the command:

```
$this->uri->segment();
```

This function allows you to return a particular segment of the url. So in your case you would be calling the byAge method of the person controller. A call to $this->uri->segment(3); would return 5.